# select events happening at the same time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What I want to do is to select all events, from a table, that are happening at the same date, time and location and output them like this :

```
Event ID    Event ID in conflict
1           2
1           3
1           4
5           6
```

So if event 2 startTime is between event 1 startTime and endTime it should appear in the list.

I have these informations in a table :

- Event ID (ID)
- Event Name (name)
- Start Date (startDate)
- End Date (endDate)
- Start Time (startTime)
- End Time (endTime)
- Event Location ID (locationID)

Any suggestion on how to do this in one SELECT? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what you have done already please?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get pairs of events using a join.  To get any overlaps:

```
select e.eventid, e2.eventid
from events e join
     events e2
     on e.starttime < e2.endtime and
        e.endtime > e2.starttime and
        e.eventid < e2.eventid;
```

Actually, your specific question is not about overlaps.  So, for your specific question:

```
select e.eventid, e2.eventid
from events e join
     events e2
     on e2.starttime between e.starttime and e.endtimee;
```

However, I suspect the more general overlap logic may be appropriate for your needs.